# Kivy BoxLayout - move widgets to the top

Tags: python, kivy

I have all the widgets sized and positioned relative to one another.  If I add a "Label:" to the bottom of the kv code it will move everything up to the top.  But that can't be the "right" way to do it.   What am I missing?

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<Controller>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 20
        spacing: 20
        TextInput:
            hint_text: 'Feed Name'
            multiline: False
            size_hint: (0.75, None)
            height: 30
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
        TextInput:
            hint_text: 'Feed URL'
            multiline: True
            size_hint: (0.75, None)
            height: 68
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
        Button:
            text: 'Add Feed'
            padding: (10, 10)
            height: 30
            size_hint: (None, None)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
''')

class Controller(BoxLayout):
    pass

class PodcastApp(App):
      def build(self):
          return Controller(info='Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PodcastApp().run()
```

Comment: If you add `Label` then that's the obvious behaviour you should see, as you have not given any size_hint to the that Label, I think you should learn that how size_hint, pos_hint actually work. See here, http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html

Comment: The Label thing is hacky and I'm sure it's the WRONG way to fix it. I've read the pos_hint and size_hint stuff over and over again. The Boxlayout only allows pos_hints of x, right, and center_x, which I used to center the widgets. The problem is I can't push all the widgets to the top. And it seems silly that bottom is the default position (seems backwards). What property will do push the widgets to the top?

Answer (score 1):

From the BoxLayout [docs](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html#api):

> padding Added in 1.0.0 Padding between layout box and children:
>   [padding_left, padding_top, padding_right, padding_bottom].
>
> padding also accepts a two argument form [padding_horizontal,
>   padding_vertical] and a one argument form [padding].
>
> Changed in version 1.7.0: Replaced NumericProperty with
>   VariableListProperty.
>
> padding is a VariableListProperty and defaults to [0, 0, 0, 0].

Try adding a padding to the bottom of the boxlayout if you want it's children to get pushed toward the top.

for instance giving the padding a value of

```
[20, 20, 20, 'new bottom padding here']
```